# Как создать пункт меню из расширения на Joomla?

Tags: joomla

Я пишу свое расширение на Joomla и мне нужно создать новый пункт меню в определенный момент работы расширения.
Как лучше это сделать?

Comment: что означает "в определенный момент работы расширения" ? более детально скажите что хотите сделать

Comment: имеем расширение на джумле. Предположим в джумле создано меню с тремя пунктами (каждый пункт меню - ссылка на статью). Расширение должно создать четвертый пункт меню с указанной статьей. 
Интересует какие для этого нужны системные вызовы.

Comment: т.е вы хотите в автоматическом режиме создавать меню ?

Comment: да, абсолютно верно. Расширение, которое я создаю, должно иметь возможность самостоятельно создать пункт меню.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы добавить меню в `Joomla` в своём компоненте, надо использовать `Joomla Menu Model`, например:

```
<?php
$menuTable = JTableNested::getInstance('Menu');
$menuData = array(
  'menutype' => 'тип_вашего_меню', /* Тип меню должен быть латиницей и быть уникальным*/
  'title' => 'Название меню',
  'alias' => 'Алиас меню',
  'url' => 'URL menu', /* URL  меню   например  :index.php?com_yourcomponent&......     */
  'path' => 'Seo URL', /* Seo URL  меню     например:  path/component_path/last_item/   */
  'type' => 'component',  /* внутренний тип меню*/
  'component_id' => 0,     /* ID компонента в #__extensions  */             
  'language' => '*',
  'published' => 1,
);


$parent_id = 1; /* если это дочернее меню, тут прописывается ID родителя */
$menuTable->setLocation($parent_id, 'last-child');

if (!$menuTable->save($menuData))
{
  $this->setError($menuTable->getError());
  return false;
}

?>
```